# error Too few arguments to function

Tags: laravel

me podría ayudar con un error que tengo, reviso en los logs y me sale "Too few arguments to function".

en la ruta esta :

```
Route::get('/venta/fechas', 'VentaController@busquedafecha');
```

Controlador:

```
public function busquedafecha(Request $request) {
```

y en el archivo vues

```
listarVentafecha(page,buscar,buscarF) {
    let me=this;
    var url= '/venta/fechas?page=' + page + '&buscar='+ buscar + '&buscarF='+ buscarF;
```

Agradecería si me pueden ayudar.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Ordena tu pregunta. En que log the sale eso? sobre que funcion? en que linea? podra ser algo de adentro de alguna funcion? estas mostrando cosas salteadas pero no parece que muestres el problema...

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente lo que estas preguntando.

Comment: Aparentemente todo se ve bien, tal ves el error sea en otro lado, pero puedes verificar si las variables estan llegando a la funcion `busquedafecha`
imprimiendo el $request dd($request->all()); y debería salir page, buscar y buscarF